# How to fix Lenovo L22e displays connected to an M1 Mac Mini when they sleep and do not wake?

Tags: macos, display, monterey, power-management

M1 Mac mini (M1, 2020), with 2 Lenovo L22e-20 monitors.

I left the Mac unattended for 10 minutes, when I came back, 1 monitor is still on but the other has gone to sleep.

The one that stays on is connected via Thunderbolt, the one that goes to sleep is connected via HDMI.

I can't wake the HDMI monitor up by turning the monitor off and on.

The only solution that has ever worked is rebooting the Mac.

If I check Energy Saver preferences, `turn display off` is set to 1 hour.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Try in Displays setting : hold option key then click Detect Display (bottom right)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that next time it goes to sleep @PtitXav

Comment: @PtitXav, unfortunately that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to this problem:

Goto to the Menu Bar **Apple** > **Sleep** after moving the mouse or pressing a key the screen will awake.

If the menu is on the HDMI screen use the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd> after moving the mouse or press a key the screen will awake.